# UEFI blankscreen after motherboard splash screen

Tags: system-installation, uefi

I installed a Ubuntu xenial UEFI using the minimal cd.

Using the whole disk, here is my partition:
/dev/sda1 512MB ESP
/dev/sda2 rest of space lvm

Lvm:
Swap 
Root ext4
home ext4

After the installation I only get a blank screen after the Asus splash screen.

In the bot options I have two uefi Ubuntu items.
I tried checking the flash info using ez utility and found that
fs0:\EFI\ubuntu\ to be empty, is this normal?

Here is my bios bot menu
[image]

Motherboard: P8H61-M LX Rev.03

Answer (score 0):

It would help though if you looked at the logs and gave us some more information on any errors that you find. Can you get to the command line using *Ctrl-Alt-F1* ? If you can't do that, then you perhaps have to enter the Grub menu during boot and boot into recovery mode under the Advanced options. You will then be able to get to the command line. I believe one holds down *Shift* to get into the grub menu, although it may differ depending on your system.

Some thoughts -

You may have to insert `nomodeset` into the `/etc/defaults/grub` file, as the system may be having a problem with the graphics driver or screen.

It might look something like this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset quiet splash"
```

It may also help to define the screen resolution in the grub file as well, for instance my file states

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080
```

Remember to update the grub file using

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Nah, the installer made the installation difficult instead of the opposite. I decided to install Gentoo. Thanks for your response anyway.